# New FileStream already closed/disposed?

Tags: c#, file-io, compact-framework

I open a `FileStream` with `FileMode.Open` and `FileAccess.Read`. Shortly after that I call a function to handle the file's contents. I use `Invoke` to make the call because the call comes from a `Thread` and the function has to put the results on a `Form`. The function accepts any kind of Stream (I call it with `MemoryStream`s too without a problem) and uses `XmlTextReader` to read the XML in the `FileStream`, but on rare occasions for unknown reasons even the first `Read()` throws an `ObjectDisposedException` and the stream's `CanRead` property returns false if the stream was already closed.

In the `Thread` the `FileStream` is a local `using` variable, so I don't think another threads should be able to close it, and I don't close it until the `Invoke` returned. There are no `Exceptions` thrown so the file is definetly there (since there is no `FileNotFoundException`) and should be accessed properly (since there is no `UnauthorizedAccessException` and `IOException`).

How could my `FileStream` still look closed sometimes just after opened?

(It might matter that I'm running my code on a Windows CE 5 device with Compact Framework 3.5 and I wasn't able to reproduce the same behaviour on my desktop PC with XP yet.)

**EDIT:**
I know, that this Invoke is ugly but that alone can't be a reason to fail, can it? (And, in most of the cases it doesn't fail at all.)

```
//the code in the thread
//...
using (FileStream fs = File.Open(assemblyPath + "\\white.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    mainForm.Instance.Invoke(new DataHandler(mainForm.Instance.handleData), new object[] { fs });
}
//...

//and the handler
public void handleData(Stream stream)
{
    infoPanel.SuspendLayout();
    try
    {
        using (XmlTextReader xml = new XmlTextReader(stream))
        {
            //it doesn't matter what is here
        }
    }
    catch{}
}
```

Comment: it sounds like the thread that opened the file has closed the stream before the other thread has had a chance to work on it.  Most likely you should be fully processing the file in the thread that opened it, and use `Invoke` to pass either the whole string, or incremental notifications of progress.  But do not pass the whole Stream to `Invoke`.   Can you post your code that is opening the file and also the handler of `Invoke`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's one reason I can think of: the worker thread got aborted.  This will run the finally block generated by the *using* statement and close the file.  How it could be aborted is a secondary question.  Is the thread's IsBackground property set to true?  Is the program bombing on an unhandled exception elsewhere and shutting down?  Just guesses of course.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, this is expected behavior.  You call Invoke, which marshals the call to another thread.  The calling thread then continues to run and the using block exits, calling Dispose on the stream.  This Dispose is happening before you are done (and maybe before you start) using the stream in the UI thread.  The exact timing of these actions is going to depend on processor load and some other factors, but it's certainly unsafe.

Either don't put the stream in a using block or better yet have the thread do the read and pass the *results* to the UI via Invoke.

**EDIT**

As Hans points out in the comment, the above explanation should be for a BeginInvoke call, which underneath calls PostMessage.  Invoke, on the other hand, uses SendMessage.  Both propbably uses some WM_COPYDATA shenanigans (I've not looked to see) to marshal the data.

The Invoke call *should* be executing the entire handler you have posted, though the behavior you see indicates otherwise.  From the code you posted there's no real way for us to determine what is closing the stream.

I would still refactor what you've done here because right now you're tying up both the UI and worker threads with the reader operation.  I'd do the read work in the worker thread and then pass the results to the UI.  This would decrease the odds of the reader work causing UI choppiness and would eliminate the possibility of the stream getting closed while you're reading from it.

Comment: Nope, you describe what happens when you use BeginInvoke.  The OP is using Invoke.

Answer (score 1):

I saw the same issue on some embedded board (ARM) I'm working on. Then I created a little test.

The following code (not involving any Threads!) crashes:

```
    using (var w = new StreamWriter(File.Create("file.txt"), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            w.WriteLine("Test");
        }
    }
```

This code however does not crash:

```
    using (var w = File.CreateText("file.txt"))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            w.WriteLine("Test");
        }
    }
```

So, my guess can only be that the underlying native code treats text files differently than when you open the file using File.Create(). Both files are then written in UTF-8, so there is no difference about the encoding.

BTW: sorry I'm one year late on the answer, but I hope it'll help somebody